# How do I see list of component in my Oracle Cloud portal?

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Although I have administrator role, I am not able to view the list of component in oracle cloud portal, it says that "You are not authorized to manage compartments". Can anyone please help me out how this issue could be resolved.

Any pointers will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please check in Identity>Users menu if you are really the member of "Administrators" group? Administrators group by default have a policy called Tenant Admin Policy which has a statement:

`ALLOW GROUP Administrators to manage all-resources IN TENANCY`

With this you should be able to manage compartments, as well. If you are the member of a different group, you might ask an admin from Administrators group to add your user to Administrators group, or you might request the admin to add a specific policy to your group. You can find more details about policies and example policies here: https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/Identity/Concepts/overview.htm